# How to use the Video widget in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using Kivy's [Video](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.video.html) widget to display a certain video file. I'm on `Windows 8 x64`. Here's the video-related entries from the start log:

```
[DEBUG             ] [Video       ] Ignored <ffmpeg> (import error)
[DEBUG             ] [Video       ] Ignored <pyglet> (import error)
[INFO              ] [Video       ] Provider: null(['video_ffmpeg', 'video_pyglet'] ignored)
```

The output shows a white square in place of the video. The thing is that Kivy doesn't seem to care about the video at all. Even if I use a non-existing `source` argument it doesn't complain.

I'm using Kivy 1.8.0 and Python 3.4.1.

Comment: What Kivy version and Python version? And are you using the portable package, or did you install Kivy into an existing Python installation?

Comment: @RyanP I added the versions in the question body. I installed Kivy on a pre-existing virtualenv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should think about upgrading to Kivy 1.9.0. We have added a ton of bug fixes and features in this new version.

As the log shows, you have no video provider available. Kivy will ignore the source on any video element, because it has no provider to use to load the video.

The easiest way to get video working is to [use the portable package](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installing-the-portable-version), which contains an installation of Kivy which has been built with video support.

We're working on creating a wheel which would include the necessary libs and could easily be installed in an existing Python installation in Windows. Until then, if you want to use your own installation, then you need to have the gstreamer libs and headers available when you build and install Kivy. Kivy 1.9.0 requires SDL2 libs and headers as well (we are dropping pygame in favor of SDL2).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The startup options are not very IDE-friendly but at least pycharm has an integrated terminal, so I can launch the main script from there, using `kivy.bat`.